# How to read pixel from a rendered texture (colorattachment)

Tags: opengl, pixel, opentk, fbo, glreadpixels

I rendered color and position textures to colorattachment0 and colorattachment1 in a fbo. The color texture is being drawn onto a cube for differed rendering. I need to read from the position texture though, which I sent to colorattachment1. Here is what ive tried:

```
public float[] getUV() 
{
    float[] uv = new float[2];
    var pixel = new float[4];
    GL.ReadBuffer(ReadBufferMode.ColorAttachment1);
    GL.ReadPixels((int)curPoint.X, (int)curPoint.Y, 1, 1, OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL.PixelFormat.Rgba, PixelType.UnsignedByte, pixel);

    uv[0] = pixel[0];
    uv[1] = pixel[1];
    return uv;
}
```

I call getUV on a mousedown event. Here is how I created my fbo:

```
    GL.Ext.GenFramebuffers(1, out fboHandle);
    GL.Ext.BindFramebuffer(FramebufferTarget.FramebufferExt, fboHandle);
    GL.Ext.FramebufferTexture2D(FramebufferTarget.FramebufferExt, FramebufferAttachment.ColorAttachment0Ext, TextureTarget.Texture2D, colorTexture, 0);
    GL.Ext.FramebufferTexture2D(FramebufferTarget.FramebufferExt, FramebufferAttachment.ColorAttachment1Ext, TextureTarget.Texture2D, uvTexture, 0);
    GL.Ext.FramebufferTexture2D(FramebufferTarget.FramebufferExt, FramebufferAttachment.DepthAttachmentExt, TextureTarget.Texture2D, depthBufferTexture, 0);
```

The values returned from getUV() are totally wrong, I think im missing a step. Ive verified ColorAttachment1 renders correctly, and that the mouse coordinates I am sending to ReadPixels is correct.

Comment: What does "totally wrong" mean? What values do you get, and what do you expect? Read back data as unsigned bytes into an float array is probably not what you want, though.

Comment: @derhass that was it, I dont know how I missed that. Thanks.